# uninitialized constant on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm trying to build my first contact form, that would send someone's name, email and message to my email address to me. I've seen quite a lot of tutorials and answered questions on stackoverflow, but it didn't help me to fix the problem I'm having. I know it has something to do with the routing but I can't figure what and why.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant ContactController
```

Here are my files :

**routes.rb**

```
match '/send_mail', to: 'contact#send_mail', via: 'post'
match '/mail', to: 'contact#contact', via: 'get'
```

**controllers/contacts_controller.rb**

```
def send_mail
name = params[:name]
  email = params[:email]
  body = params[:comments]
  ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver
  redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message sent'
end
```

**mailers/contact_mailer.rb**

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: 'mymail@gmail.com'

      def contact_email(name, email, body)
        @name = name
        @email = email
        @body = body`enter code here`

        mail(from: email, subject: 'Contact Request')
      end
end
```

**views/contact.html.twig**

```
<div class="container-content">
  <div class="container">
    <%= form_tag(send_mail_path) do %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag 'name', 'Name' %>
          <%= text_field_tag 'name', nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'John Doe' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag 'email', 'Email' %>
          <%= email_field_tag 'email', nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'johndoe@domain.com' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= label_tag 'comments', 'Comments' %>
          <%= text_area_tag 'comments', nil, class: 'form-control', rows: 4, placeholder: 'How can I help you?' %>
        </div>
        <%= submit_tag nil, class: 'btn btn-default btn-about' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**views/contact_email.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Mail received from <%= "#{ @name } (#{ @email }):" %></p>
    <p><%= @body %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**config/initializers.rb**

```
module Contact
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
    config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

**initializers/stmp_config.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "gmail.com",
    :user_name            => "mymail@gmail.com",
    :password             => "password",
    :authentication       => :login,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

As I'm newbie in the rails world, I'm not sure at all of what I'm doing, but I've seen a lot of tutorials where people had a code similar to mine, but no one seems to have this problem

Where did i go wrong ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace (formatted) to your question/

Comment: `uninitialized constant ContactController` means that Rails tried to find `ContactController` in `app/controllers/contact_controller.rb` and failed. The most likely explainations is that the file has the wrong name or that the class declared in the file has the wrong name.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to change your routes.rb as follows (contacts instead of contact):

```
match '/send_mail', to: 'contacts#send_mail', via: 'post'
match '/mail', to: 'contacts#contact', via: 'get'
```

Comment: i tried it, it gave me the following error : `Unable to autoload constant ContactsController, expected C:/Users/Drillan767/RubymineProjects/contact/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb to define it`

Comment: It is probably another problem with some naming. I would now look at the controller. Would you attach the complete content of contacts_controller.rb?

Answer (score 1):

Thats one way to create a contact form - however its not really a *Rails app*. Its just an app that happens to be using Rails.

This is how you can use the Rails conventions to make this more robust and less messy.

### Model

Lets generate a model and migration:

```
$ rails g model enquiry name:string email:string body:text
```

Then we run the migration:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

So why create a model if we are just sending an email? Because email fails. And you don't want to lose important enquiries from potential customers.

We also want our model to validate that the user provides the required fields:

```
# app/models/enquiry.rb
model Enquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :email, :body
  validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
end
```

### Controller

Lets create a RESTful route:

```
# config/routes.rb 
# ...
resources :enquiries, only: [:new, :create]
```

Note that we are calling it `enquiries`. Instead of using an procedure oriented `send_contact` route we have the resource `enquiries` which gives us conventions for how to show, create and update it.

You can see what routes are generated with `$ rake routes`.

See [Resource Routing: the Rails Default](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

Lets create a controller for our new route:

```
# app/controllers/enquiries_controller.rb
# note controllers use the plural form
class EnquiriesController < ApplicationController
   # GET '/enquiries/new'
   def new 
     @enquiry = Enquiry.new
   end
   # POST '/enquiries'
   def create
     @enquiry = Enquiry.new(enquiry_params)
     if @enquiry.save
       ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver
       redirect_to root_path, success: 'Thanks for getting in touch, we will look into it ASAP.'
     else
       render :new
     end
   end

   private 
     def enquiry_params
       params.require(:enquiry).permit(:name, :email, :body)
     end
end
```

### View

We also need a form:

```
# app/views/enquiries/new.html.erb
<%= form_for(@enquiry) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

By using a form builder and a model our form will automatically "play back" the values if the user submits an invalid form.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your detailed answer, I followed it all, but when i went to see /enquiries/new, I had the following error message : `undefined method `action' for EnquiriesController:Class`

Comment: Hmm, thats a really strange error message. Are you sure its not some sort of copy-paste error?

Comment: I've rewritten the whole code myself, it didn't change anything.. and I can't get a precise line where the error happens, even though I'm trying to change details such as [at]enquiry => [at]enquiries, etc

Comment: Ah, I see what I did wrong now. I forgot to setup EnquiriesController so that inherits from ApplicationController. Edited the answer.

Comment: I edited my code, it worked fine, until when i pressed "send", when i had `undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass` in enquiries_controller.rb:8:in `create', and I also have a question, is it inenquiries_controller.rb > create that i put a default mail to send the mail to ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: My bad again, the offending line should be `@enquiry = Enquiry.new(enquiry_params)`

Comment: You would set the `default from` option in your mailer class - not in the controller. But its usually better to set the option in one place by setting `ActionMailer::Base.default(from: 'foo@example.com')` then to spread it all over all your mailers.

Comment: Hello again, i'm sorry i come back to you only now, i couldn't do it earlier. I tried what you said in a test in local but i now have the following when i click on send: `undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass, app/controllers/enquiries_controller.rb:9:in 'create' `, it seems that he doesn't understand what "Enquiry.new" wants to mean... thank you in advance

Comment: I really botched that edit - edited. should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in 'ContactController' - it's must be in plural: 'ContactsController'!